# Missing ssh-keygen command on my system and need to generate keys

Tags: ssh, ssh-keys

I guess the simplest answer would be install openSSH, however this is not so easy in my case.

This is small router without packaging system, all is at flash disk. I don't want to install packaging system, rather to find solution how to generate keys for this device.

Question is: Is it possible to generate keys for my small router on completely different machine and how to implement them then later to my small router?

Comment: Keys are generally not device specific. Long as you have a valid private key for the public key you're distributing it should work, though as wurtel mentions you may have to convert from one key storage format to another for the particular system.

Answer (score 0):

Basically: yes.

You may have to convert the format it's stored in.

Do you have an alternate SSH utility on this system? If not, why the need for ssh keys? If you do, then investigate it further as it probably *does* come with something that can generate keys itself can use.